# Errors with my argument error handing

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, argparse, command-line-arguments

I'm creating an error for passing this argument. Where if the user doesn't enter 'followers' or 'following' it tells them. The problem is, the error is coming up when I enter the correct argument as well.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('iStats')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--relationship', help='Followers or Following', required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['relationship'] is not 'following' or 'followers':
    parser.error("argument MUST be followers OR following")
```

Error I'm getting

```
C:\Users\Daniel>istats.py -r following
usage: iStats [-h] [-r RELATIONSHIP]
iStats: error: argument MUST be followers OR following
```

**EDIT:**
After reassessing my understanding, I have updated my code with the preferred method.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('iStats')
parser.add_argument('-r', '--relationship', choices=['following', 'followers'], help='Choose following or followers.', required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

Comment: Your understanding of boolean logic is flawed; it is not like english grammar. Use `if args['relationship'] not in ('following', 'followers'):`. Better yet, use the [`choices` option](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#choices) to `parser.add_argument()` and have `argparse` validate the possible values.

Comment: Went with choices. Thanks!